# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DESCR

Tags: java, drools

When I try the
http://www.softwarepassion.com/getting-started-with-drools-flow/ tutorial
I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DESCR
       at
org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:539)
       at
org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:28)
       at
com.softwarepassion.droolsflow.SPDroolsFlowExample.readKnowledgeBase(SPDroolsFlowExample.java:30)
       at
com.softwarepassion.droolsflow.SPDroolsFlowExample.main(SPDroolsFlowExample.java:20)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

This usually indicates incompatible versions of two libraries. Get the most up-to-date jars of drools and try again. Also make sure you don't have multiple versions on the classpath.

Comment: thanks bhozho my problem was i have used multiple versions of same jar on the class path that was the problem

Comment: You saved my coffee break ;)